# load from parse 25k rows in array and show in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I am a beginner in objective-c and I can't figure this out to implement in my app.
I managed to load rows (with 4 columns) from parse in array and show in table view. But I can't manage to load all 3k rows. I know about the 1000 limit. Please guide me how to put the pointer each time after the 1000 read.

```
self.parseClassName = @"LocalitatiMari";

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    return query;  
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ROviDRGCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    //PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
    //PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    //thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"];
    //thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail;
    //[thumbnailImageView loadInBackground];



    if (self.tableView.tag !=100 )
    {
        UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
        nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"CodPostal"];

        UILabel *prepTimeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
        prepTimeLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Oras"];

        UILabel *codnumenou = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:103];
        codnumenou.text = [object objectForKey:@"Judet"];

        UILabel *strada = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:105];
        strada.text = [object objectForKey:@"Strada"];

            }
    else
    {
        PFObject *objects = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
        nameLabel.text = [objects objectForKey:@"CodPostal"];

        UILabel *prepTimeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
        prepTimeLabel.text = [objects objectForKey:@"Oras"];

        UILabel *codnumenou = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:103];
        codnumenou.text = [objects objectForKey:@"Judet"];

        UILabel *strada = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:105];
        strada.text = [objects objectForKey:@"Strada"];


    }



    return cell;
}

- (void) objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error
{
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];

    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

}

Comment: You *never* want to download 25K objects.  The app should only download objects that can be shown and then as the user scrolls it will do incremental downloads to continuously display items in the view. You can experiment with batch sizes, but I guess 30 items is a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the data via a persistent mechanism after downloading the data, so you don't have to keep it all in memory.

Core data is one option.

If you save them to core data, then all your other issues already have well known and well used patterns (e.g., letting `NSFetchedResultsController` bridge between your data and your table view).

> the problem is I can't manage to download all the data. I fetch the
>   first 1000 rows, but then I can't fetch more rows. I made the for loop
>   in - (PFQuery *)queryForTable, but no results. Please quide me how to
>   implement it so i can get more than 1000 rows from parse. – Lalu

Having never used parse, I don't know.  However, seeing as it is a network API, and they do have a fetch limit, I can't imagine that they encourage blasting N queries at the same time in a for-loop.

I would think that you should kick off one query, and then when that one has finished, start another one where the previous one left off until you have all the objects you need.

Interested in seeing how difficult it is to discover how to do this, I entered a simple google search for "[parse.com query more than 1000](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=parse.com%20query%20more%20than%201000)" which results in a page full of answers for this exact question, and quickly landed me on a forum discussion entitled "[Paging through more than 10,000 results.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/GmIt3OG2m8o)" where there is an example that verifies what I said above.

Comment: the problem is I can't manage to download all the data. I fetch the first 1000 rows, but then I can't fetch more rows. I made the for loop in - (PFQuery *)queryForTable, but no results. Please quide me how to implement it so i can get more than 1000 rows from parse.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine why you want to download 25k objects at once, to display it in a table view. Who should look at this huge table?
But if you really want to download 25k objects from Parse, you had to issue 25 queries, 1000 objects each. And the i-th query (starting with i = 0) had to be constrained by a `query.skip = i*1000;` see [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-query-constraints).

Comment: I am thinking to split the 25k to smaller classes, but some of them will have around 2000 rows. Can't make them smaller unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, but where to implement the quere.skip?in query for table?

Comment: I still can't manage to fetch more than 1000 rows. I implemented for loop in - (PFQuery *)queryForTable but with no results. Please help me how to implement it so it works.

Comment: I still don’t see any reason why you want to do this in a table view.   
Why don’t you just use for testing purposes a for loop with index i starting at 0, where in the body a query is set up for 1000 objects with a skip constraint of i*1000.
You had to store then the individual objects downloaded from Parse in separate places (depending on the index), and to merge them after all callbacks have been received.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable i in a loop starting from zero and increment by 1 each time and use query.skip(i*1000) but that loop will also run upto 10000 only as you can't skip more than 10000 rows. Beyond that, you will have to set the skip to zero and add a constraint that for updatedAt and select only the old rows.